# onKeyDown() in Android not working for virtual keys

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-menu

I had been searching a lot about this thing, but could not figure it out. So I thought to ask here what exactly the problem I am facing, so that it could help others also (who might face the same problem)

I am having the following code in my Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements KeyEvent.Callback{
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Key down called");
        if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {
            System.out.println("Menu clicked");
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        System.out.println("On key up");
        if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {

            System.out.println("up Menu clicked");
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

**Where it works** (Devices having physical buttons)

If I run the same code in Android device having the **physical keys** at the bottom then these methods are getting called for `Menu` button and `Back` button.

**The Problem** (Devices having virtual keys)

But if I run the code in a device having the [Virtual keys](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html) at the bottom (rather than the physical keys) then these methods are **NOT** being called.

I am able to handle the back press (thanks to `onBackPressed()`) but not able to override the Menu button pressed for virtual keys.

Any workaround for this thing? How can I override the menu button in Android devices having Virtual keys.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Menu button in the newer versions, especially which are having virtual buttons at the bottom. It is the Recent Apps button,  which has this predefined functionality to show recent applications and it can't be overridden.